# Any way to save changes to the "open file" window side-bar layout?

Tags: interface

I'm talking about this side-bar where file locations are listed in different panels. There's the 'volumes' panel, the 'System' panel, the 'Favorites' panel and the 'recent' panel.
[image]

I know I can change the order of the panels by clicking and dragging them, but the changes are not saved. Every time I open a file the order of the panels is reset.
Is there any way to save the changes to the 'open file' window?